# Jetty and max content size

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I use Jetty 9.4.8 and i want limits the amount of data that can post to the server. For that i added to jetty.xml:

```
<Call name="setAttribute">
  <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize</Arg>
  <Arg>10000</Arg>
</Call>
```

I tested jetty like (request-xxlarge.xml - text file(20mb)):

```
curl -X POST --data @request-xxlarge.xml http://localhost:8080/test -v
```

As a result i got

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 21232818
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 4
< Connection: close
< Server: Jetty(9.4.8.v20171121)
< 
* Closing connection 0
POST
```

server processed the request

**EDITED**

The server returns 413 when Content-Type: application / x-www-form-urlencoded.

But if I expect it to be a web service and i want to process Content-Type: application / soap + xml - then the maxFormContentSize parameter does not work.

How can I limit the size of the body for a web service?

Comment: Please show your servlet that is handling the POST request. (also, where you configured this limit in your deployed webapp)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, my servlet just `resp.getWriter().write("POST\n");` and the limit i set only in jetty.xml.

Comment: Does your servlet at least it read the POST body content that was sent? using `request.getParts()` or `request.getParameterMap()`? (there's nothing to trigger the limit until you do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 limits that Jetty can impose on request body content based on specific `Content-Type` values.

### Content-Type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

This is the standard html `<form>` submission, where the submitted form is accessed via the [`HttpServletRequest.getParameter(String key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) API.

This kind of request body content can be filtered in 2 different ways.

`org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize` - this is a limit on the overall size (in bytes) of the request body content.

`org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys` - this is a limit on the overall number of form keys of the form being submitted.

The above 2 keys expect integer values, and can be set in any of the following techniques ...

#### 1) As a Server attribute that applies to all deployed webapps

```java
Server.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize", 100000)
```

#### 2) As a System Property that applies to all deployed webapps

```sh
$ java -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=100000 \
       -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar
```

or

```java
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize", "1000000")
```

#### 3) As a Context parameter on the deployed `WebAppContext`

In your `${jetty.base}/webapps/<context>.xml` you can set these values

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/mycontext</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps"/>/mycontext.war</Set>

  <Set name="maxFormKeys">100</Set>
  <Set name="maxFormContentSize">202020</Set>
</Configure>
```

### Content-Type: `multipart/form-data`

This is also a standard form submission as above, but the data can also be accessed via the [`HttpServletRequest.getPart(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart-java.lang.String-) APIs.

This kind of data is restricted via the configuration present for the destination Servlet's [`@MultipartConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) values (or `WEB-INF/web.xml` entries for the `<servlet><multipart-config>` elements)

To limit this kind of content type by entire request size, use the `maxRequestSize` configuration.

### All other request Content-Type entries

For all other `Content-Type` values, the servlet spec, and Jetty are not involved in parsing or limiting the size.

If you are using a library to handle your requests (REST, SOAP, etc) then check with that library to see if it has a mechanism to reject requests based on size, or other reasons (eg: not well-formed, missing expected/required data, etc).

As always, if you want a feature, feel free to request it on the Eclipse Jetty issue tracker at
https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: I submitted an enhancement request to make those be able to be set from `WEB-INF/web.xml` too - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2325

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure what your issue is, but I'll give it a shot.*

###Theory###
The `Expect: 100-continue` header is specified in `HTTP 1.1` and allows the server to acknowledge or reject a POST/PUT request immediately after the headers are send but before the client starts sending potentially large amounts of actual data (body of the request). Thus, a conforming client must then wait for a `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` before sending the data. This scheme is advantageous for larger POST/PUT requests since in the case of rejection the client and server don't waste their time with superfluous network communication.

###Possible Solutions###

1. Disable Expect Logic

   curl -H 'Expect:' -H 'Transfer-Encoding: ...' -H 'Content-Type: ...' 
   --data-binary '@mediumfile' example.com/path -v
2. Send next packet with the big file as expected after the first response packet.

More info here : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1